# Добавление контента в собранное приложение на юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, windows

нужна возможность менять/добавлять контент в собранном приложении на юнити для пк на виндовс.

То есть что то типо админки для приложения. Подскажите, есть ли какие то способы создать такое на юнити?

Задача такая: Есть приложение с разными разделами и в один из разделов нужно постоянно добавлять данные, а именно тизер новости и в последующем страницу этой новости. То есть нужно создавать кнопку с превью и страницу с контентом.

Может как то можно прикрутить xml или другие таблицы и чтобы юнити подтягивала данные из нее.

Пока есть такой вариант. Все сделать на хтмл + админка на пхп и в юнити просто отображать данные с хтмл + дать возможность входить в админку. Но проблема в том, что админки делать я не умею)). Но этот вопрос более менее решаемый.

Вот интересует возможность добавления контента средствами юнити. Палками не кидаться, я с юнити всего месяц как знаком.

Answer (score 0):

Я как понял вы хотите создать новостную страницу типа такого:[image: Знаю это странный пример]

То в таком случае будет лучше сделать небольшую базу данных или раздел в ней и там хранить картинки(вроде MySQL можно хранить картинки) и весь текст к ней. А затем Unity будет подключатся к базе данных и подгружать их.

Или же есть еще вариант если у вас есть сайт игры. Можно написать парсер для сайта. Когда вы будите добавлять новую новость на сайт то парсер заметит это и скопирует с сайта картинки и весь текст в игру.

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления контента в приложение на Unity с помощью админки можно использовать базу данных, файлы (XML, JSON), систему AssetBundle или веб-технологии. Самым простым решением будет использование системы AssetBundle.